# "expected an indented block" when using except: continue

Tags: python

When running below code:

```
for line in file:
    try:
        result = dataclass.from_json(line)
    except Error as error:
        # ignore records for non-matches
    continue
```

I received

> "expected an indented block"

Comment: Because `continue` should be indented. First, you try to execute `result = dataclass.from_json(line)`. If it fails, you want to execute `continue`. So it should be within the `except` block.

Comment: *"expected an indented block"* so did you try indenting `continue` one tab space?

Answer (score 1):

The right shape of a `try - except` statement is:

```
for line in [1,2,3]:
    try:
        result = 0
    except ValueError:
        # ignore records for non-matches
        continue
```

statement `continue` (which roughly means "don't do nothing") is *inside* the `except` block, so you need an identation.